# Cone of effective divisors!

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $X$ be a smooth simply connected projective variety of dimension $n$ (over complex numbers of course). For such $X$ we have two famous cones which are cone of effective curves and ample cone and are dual to each other.

Question: Is there any thing as Cone of effective divisors? Is there any problem to define such a thing? Has any body studied that?
For surfaces, it is just cone of effective curves. So the smallest dimension at which we would get some thing new is three.

Comment: People do study the cone of effective divisors. Check out the book "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I" by Lazarfeld.

Comment: You are right, It is mentioned in definition 2.2.25 but there is not much discussion on it's structure. 

Comment: Let $X$ be a projective variety. By applying concept of Mori equivalence, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1030132722 , we can decompose the cone of effective divisors on $X$ into convex polyhedral chambers which called Mori chambers. In fact the best way  to define a Mori dream space is if it has a good Mori chamber decomposition.

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned in the comments, the *(pseudo)effective cone* $\overline{\mathrm{Eff}}(X)$, defined as the closure of the cone of all effective divisors on $X$, is certainly an object of study, and Lazarsfeld's book is a good reference.  Your complaint that he doesn't say much about its structure is surely related to the fact that so little is known!  Here are a few general things I'm aware of:

- The interior of the effective cone is the *big cone*, i.e., the cone of line bundles with positive volume.
- The dual of the effective cone is the *cone of moveable curves*, see Boucksom-Demailly-Paun-Peternell.
- As part of their work on the minimal model program, Birkar-Cascini-Hacon-McKernan prove that log Fano varieties have finitely generated effective cones.

And here are a couple specific instances where one knows more:

- When $X$ admits an action by a solvable group with a dense orbit, the effective cone is generated by the components of the complement of the orbit.  (This works when $X$ is, e.g., a toric variety or a Schubert variety.)
- There's been a lot of recent work on the case $X=\overline{M}_{0,n}$, see e.g., Hu-Keel, Hassett-Tschinkel, Castravet-Tevelev.